# Can the Hulk talk?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-incredible-hulk

I was under the impression that The Hulk was incapable of speech, but I just saw *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* again, and in the scene where Loki tells The Hulk to worship him as a God, The Hulk beats Loki mercilously before saying "Puny god!"

Are there other examples of The Hulk talking?

Comment: Yes, his catchphrase is "Hulk smash!".

Comment: He also says: "Arrrghgh" and "Wwwrrhhhaarrrggg"! In fact, if you listen closely, you can make out proper sentences, the problem is that his speech is drowned out by the sounds of buildings collapsing and the dying screeches of his victims!

Comment: @Mooz: Yep, I'm pretty sure this one time when he was doing even more beating than usual, he smiled knowingly, quietly said, "So we beat on, boats against the current," and went back to beating things.

Comment: In Infinity War, the Hulk repeatedly says "No" to coming out. While he uses Bruce's body to do so, it's clearly the Hulk saying it.

Comment: I read the Marvel comics through the '70s and 80s and he could always talk. The only time that he couldn't was in the 1978 TV series.

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of universes in which Hulk can talk normally, but just considering Earth-616, we have [a few](http://hulk.wikia.com/wiki/Hulk).

**Joe Fixit**

> Gray Hulk/Joe Fixit – The Gray Hulk (though not the original) worked for a time as a Las Vegas enforcer called "Joe Fixit". The Gray Hulk has poor intelligence, although he occasionally displays knowledge and intellectual ability normally associated with Banner.

**Professor Hulk**

> Merged/Professor Hulk – The Merged Hulk is the merger of Banner and the Savage and Gray Hulks. The Merged Hulk was later retconned into The Professor. The Professor, rather than being a merger of the three main personalities, was interpreted as a fourth, separate personality that represented Banner's ideal self. The primary difference between the two is that the Merged Hulk demonstrated aspects of the Banner, Gray Hulk and Savage Hulk personalities (also possessing Banner's intelligence, Joe Fixit's cunning, and the Savage Hulk's size and strength), while the Professor did not.

**World Breaker Hulk**

> World Breaker Hulk – The Hulk of World War Hulk is a cunning and more powerful version than the previous incarnations. His rage is at its most focused, due to meditation training by his ally Hiroim.

It should be noted that the other versions of the Hulk are generally described as having the intelligence and temperament of a child. He *can* talk, he just usually doesn't. These versions I mention (amongst others from across the multi-verse) are the ones that are as intelligent as, or more intelligent than a normal person.

### In the MCU

Until recently, the Hulk has demonstrated very limited ability to speak. However, *Thor Ragnarok* changed this and depicts Hulk having entire conversations with Thor.

Comment: Good information. Doesn't really address the cinematic universe (like I think CodeMed wanted), but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: I've been reading the Hulk comics from the start. I'm currently 14 years in. I don't think there's been one comic where he didn't talk.

Comment: In the early 1980s, *The Hulk* magazine rarely if every depicted the Hulk talking; however, they were explicitly trying to appeal to fans of the TV show.

Answer (score 2):

Disney XD currently has two cartoons on the air that depict Hulk in very different ways.

In "Avengers Assemble", he is a member of the Avengers, and talks once in awhile with typical dumbed-down speech patterns.

In "Hulk and the Agents of S.M.A.S.H.", he leads his own team of hulks, and talks frequently with normal speech patterns and intelligence.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Hulk incarnation, Doc Green, is 'the smartest there is' more intelligent than Banner, due to using the extremis virus to heal brain damage. However Doc Green has speculated that the effects of the extremis virus are temporary and he will return to a normal dumb Hulk state (Hulk 16, 2015).

Maestro Hulk, a Hulk from a future timeline, is extremely intelligent but evil (Future Imperfect 1, 2015).

The movie Hulk is a, for want of a better term, is a young Hulk. The incarnations of the Hulk that have been mentioned in this thread are older Hulks. Hulk appears to mature with age.

Comment: HULK STILL CHILD AT HEART!!!